# Saving process output to a file in systemd unit file

Tags: linux, centos, files, python, systemd

I created a systemd file unit (Centos 7) and I wanted to save the Python output to a file but the service won't start with the below code.

```
[root@static ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/pykms.service
[Unit]
Description=PY-KMS
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/py-kms-master/server.py 192.168.1.100 1688 -v > /usr/local/py-kms-master/pykmsss.log



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**NOTE:** if I delete the line after ">" above, then everything works fine but I want to save the logs to a file.

**systemctl status pykms -l**

```
 [root@static ~]# systemctl status pykms -l
pykms.service - PY-KMS
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pykms.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-11-24 20:54:28 IRST; 2s ago
 Main PID: 2788 (server.py)
   CGroup: /system.slice/pykms.service
           └─2788 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/py-kms-master/server.py 192.168.1.100 1688 -v

Nov 24 20:54:28 server.de systemd[1]: Starting PY-KMS...
Nov 24 20:54:28 -server.de systemd[1]: Started PY-KMS.
```

Answer (score 1):

The man page for a [systemd unit](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=systemd.service) states:

> Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.

It then goes on to explain how these can be used:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'dmesg | tac'
```

In your situation you could do this:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'exec /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/py-kms-master/server.py 192.168.1.100 1688 -v > /usr/local/py-kms-master/pykmsss.log'
```

Comment: Thank you i used your code and restarted the server but i got the error below when i wanted to see the service status

Comment: Nov 24 03:21:45 static.27.79.47.78.clients.your-server.de sh[2049]: /bin/sh: exec /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/py-kms-master/server.py 192.168.1.100 1688 -v > /usr/local/py-kms-master/kms.log: No such file or directory

Comment: i faced with this error, what should i do?

Comment: @JdeBP you're correct, the `-c` is essential. I'm not sure how I missed it from the implementation example but thank you for fixing it

Comment: it does not work. what should I do then?

Comment: @Reza it works for me. If it still doesn't work for you (with the `-c` flag) you need to explain what happens / does not happen. Error messages? Description? Edit your question to include the updated `ExecStart` line, etc.

Comment: which service Type should I use? simple, forking or ..... ?

Comment: the script works but it creates an empty log file

Comment: @reza if the script works then we've solved your issue. It's up to your program to write anything it needs to the log file.

Comment: but when is exucutes the code in command prompt it creates a log file. but in unit file it won't. what service type should i choose?

Comment: @reza update your question to include the latest output from `systemctl status pykms -l`. I don't know what your program does so I can't tell you how to debug it.

Comment: i updated as your request.

Comment: it is a kms server written in python. if i run the script from command line it shows which client connected to the server on the screen. but the above code does not generate log file so i can see which client connected.

Comment: @reza Please update your Question. Don't create an Answer when you don't have an answer.