# Empty output file in systemd unit file

Tags: linux, centos, files, systemd, kms

I created the below systemd unit file (Centos 7) to run KMS server and logs the client requests to the kms-server.txt file. The service runs without any problem and responses to the client's requests but the kms-server.txt file is empty. would you please help me to solve this problem?

```
[Unit]
Description=PY-KMS
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'exec /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/py-kms-master/server.py 192.168.1.100 1688 -v > /usr/local/$



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This is a follow-on question from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245037/ .